# Check <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> of AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, api, geolocation, android-manifest, api-key

I have the api key in the right place but I am getting the above error. I have cleaned my project and reinstalled. Below is my android Manifest. I am getting an "Error inflating class fragment caused by: android.view.InflationException: API key not found...check that ^(above)." Anyone know why or have also come across this? The other stack overflow question don't help because mine is in the correct place :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.water">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.maps.android.utils.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".OnBoardingActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCx10qvRhgY2575ZnLchGC2iTDfS5Airlc"/>

    </application>

</manifest>

Also my fragment_map.xml where error happening (at inflating fragment)...

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

...my Map.xml...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Also my BUILD GRADLE if helps to see

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.water"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api:api-common:1.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im new to programming, but what worked for me was placing meta-data above the uses permissions like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
package="com.companyname.travelrecordapp" android:installLocation="auto">
<application android:label="TravelRecordApp.Android">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
android:value="AIzaSyDXPYQlj1g15DeT7DvG9qeg1IFjRYRsrM0"/>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        </application>
```

- get key:

  1. Go to the Google Cloud Console and create a new project or select an existing one.

  2.Click on the "APIs & Services" menu on the left-hand side and select "Credentials."

  3.Click the "Create credentials" button and select "API key" from the dropdown menu.

  4.Follow the prompts to create your API key. You can choose to restrict the key to specific Android apps and/or specific APIs.

  5.Once you've created your API key, copy it and paste it into your Android app's (e.g  android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" )

- don't forget enable service e.g. Maps SDK for Android